# ffmpeg command for concatenate two mp3 files

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, php, mp3

I am using ffmpeg for Concatenating two MP3 files together,

I use this command :

```
ffmpeg -y -i first.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:a libmp3lame output.mp3
```

It works, but there is a little problem, the overlay together!

I want first song plays, and when it finished, second file starts (in output file)

But now they starts at the same time.

How can i change that command, to have a output that contains first song then when the first finished, second plays ?

Plus, I've tried `concat` command but not worked, 
I just can use something like what i sent.

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-mp3-files) stackoverflow question.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/587511/concatenate-multiple-wav-files-using-single-command-without-extra-file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To skip re-encoding, use the concat demuxer:

Create a text file

```
file '/path/to/first.mp3'
file '/path/to/second.mp3'
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy out.mp3
```

---

If re-encoding is fine,

```
ffmpeg -i first.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 out.mp3
```

Comment: thanks but i couldn't use that, is there anyway to use `amix` command?

Comment: for example adding offset to second sound with using `amix` ? I don't know why `concat` doesn't work for me.

Comment: there are two commands - which didn't work?

Comment: i've tried both of them but mainly i've no idea why they don't work, plus getting trace output is hard for me because i'm using php to doing it.

Comment: Is there anyway to add a delay to the second mp3 with `amix` ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to manually supply the duration, and volume will be reduced. `ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=75000|75000[b];[0][b]amix" out.mp3` `75000` is the duration of 2.mp3 in milliseconds.

Comment: Oh thanks soo much! is there anyway it copies metadata of 2.mp3 file too? attach it to the output.

Comment: Add `-map_metadata 1`

Comment: Thanks , how about metadata for 1.mp3? And where to add it? at the last of command?

Comment: Add `-map_metadata 0`. if any fields clash, the last specified map_metadata will overwrite the first.

Comment: @Mulvya: You should write this up as an answer if he insists on using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Add `-safe 0` before `-i` if see error: `[concat @ 0x7fcef3000000] Unsafe file name '/path/to/first.mp3'
   list.txt: Operation not permitted`

Comment: The option with re-encoding is the only solution among those I tried that results in a correct merged mp3. Could you please supply a command line that allows to speed up re-encoding at the cost of lower sound quality in the output mp3?

Comment: The ffmpeg -copy leaves a tiny glitch (in the one test I tried).  The various "cat" methods probably work correctly only when there are no ID tags.  With ID info, on the tests I tried, the bigger file looked to various programs like the first file ... and stopped playing at the same length as the first file.  I haven't found a good command line solution for the Mac yet, but www.audio-join.com did a nice job of joining two tracks with ID tags for me.  (ffmpeg also added 3 seconds of silence at the end for some reason!)

Comment: In my comment above, typo...should be www.audio-joiner.com.     I've also tried using 'sox' ... has the same problem as ffmpeg (glitch & 3 extra seconds)

Answer (score 8):

Usually,

```
cat first.mp3 second.mp3 > out.mp3
```

should just work. You didn't say what goes wrong when you try it.

Alternatively, you can use `mp3wrap`:

```
mp3wrap out.mp3 first.mp3 second.mp3 third.mp3 ...
```

This doesn't re-encode the MP3s like `ffmpeg` would, it keeps the ID3 tags, and you can split the files again later with `mp3split`.

I advise against using `ffmpeg` or similar programs, because reencoding causes loss of quality.

Comment: You're right ffmpeg is not good , but i have to currently. Is there anyway to use ffmpeg right now? concat doesn't work for me. I have to use `amix` format

Comment: if you don't re-encode doesn't that mess up the timecode?

Comment: This is the fastest way but will need some tweaking if you have spaces in the filename.

Comment: I know that the question has `ffmpeg` in the title but this solution is so simple and straightforward that it should deserve more praise. Have been using Linux for a while but  realizing the real potential of `cat` has eluded me until now. `cat * > out.mp3` worked like a charm, thanks

Comment: Perfect solution that will work on 99% of systems with minimal fuss and no encoding issues

Comment: what does this do to mp3 tags?

Comment: @cannyboy The ID3v1 record is located at the end of the file, the ID3v2 records are at the beginning. So tags from the last (ID3v1) resp. first (IDv2) file should be valid for the final file. Tags copied from other files will be ignored in the best case (and might cause trouble in the worst case), so better remove them first.

Comment: "_This doesn't re-encode the MP3s like `ffmpeg` would_" `ffmpeg` wouldn't if you set `-c copy`.

Answer (score 2):

you could also use `cat [your files] > concat.mp3` which will produce a mp3 file that has multiple headers and ID3 tags. Afterwards you can correct this by invoking `mp3val -f -nb concat.mp3`.