# ffmpeg multiple audio files + 1 image to make video file

Tags: windows, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have several flac files and an image. I have succesfully created a video of the image with a single file playing in the background.

Now, I have several of these flac files and I would like to stitch them together and have the video portion be a single image.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i "background.jpg" -i "concat:test.flac|gold.flac" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -movflags +faststart "newout.mp4"
```

where test.flac and gold.flac are two of the files i want to stitch together.

Right now, only "test.flac" plays over the image. "gold.flac" does not play and the video is the exact length of only "test.flac".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.flac -i gold.flac -framerate 1 -i "background.jpg" -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -movflags +faststart "newout.mp4"
```

I arrived at this conclusion with trial and error. I believe I was using the concat protocol that is meant to concatenate files rather than the concatenate demuxer which is used to combine streams. I might be mistaken.

Sources:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

[ffmpeg command for concatenate two mp3 files](https://superuser.com/questions/1215824/ffmpeg-command-for-concatenate-two-mp3-files)