# Concatenate (non-encoding) without creating a text file ffmpeg

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

So after all the [searches](https://superuser.com/questions/1215824/ffmpeg-command-for-concatenate-two-mp3-files?rq=1), I couldn't find anything relating to this topic. Can I do a non-encoding concatenation without having to create a text file?

Comment: Why can't you create a text file? (http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @slhck I can create a text file of course. I was just wondering; can there not be a way of having everything in one code instead of creating a separate text file.

Answer (score 3):

The `concat` demuxer can only read from a file pointer or URL. The contents of the file cannot be replaced by commandline options.

What you can do instead is to use process substitution (if your shell supports it) to generate the file [on the fly](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.wav; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.wav
```

Here, `<(…)` returns a file pointer that can be opened by `ffmpeg` as if it was a regular file.